# Why is Java adding 1h to my DateTime?

Tags: java, prepared-statement, jodatime

I have two DateTime (Joda) variables:

```
 DateTime from = new DateTime(2015, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
 DateTime to = new DateTime(2015, 3, 31, 0, 0, 0, 0);
```

I pass these variables to another method:

```
AtmosphericDb.GetParameterMetaRecords(AtmosphericParameter.Dust_Coarse, from , to);
```

These dates are used in a SQL query:

```
String sql = "SELECT * 
              FROM metalinks 
              WHERE parameter_name = ? 
              AND date_from >= ? 
              AND date_to <= ?; ";

PreparedStatement preparedStatement = metaStoreConnection.prepareStatement(sql);
preparedStatement.setString(1, parameter.name().replace('_', '-').toLowerCase());
preparedStatement.setDate(2, new java.sql.Date(from.toDate().getTime()));
preparedStatement.setDate(3, new java.sql.Date(to.toDate().getTime()));
ResultSet resultset = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
```

All works well, but when I was not getting the results I had expected, I discovered that the DateTime passed to the `to` parameter in the SQL query is not correct.

```
System.out.println(preparedStatement);
```

The above line of code prints out the following:

```
SELECT * 
FROM metalinks 
WHERE parameter_name = 'dust-coarse' 
AND date_from >= '2015-01-01 +00:00:00' 
AND date_to <= '2015-03-31 +01:00:00'
```

Now, why is there a `+01:00:00` in `2015-03-31 +01:00:00` instead of `+00:00:00`?

Comment: What time zone are you using?

Comment: @LewBloch I did not set one. I'm in the UK.

Comment: The UK moves from Standard Time, `+00:00:00`, to Summer Time, `+01:00:00`, on March 26. There seems little mystery here.

Comment: It looks like UK went on Summer Time on 2015-03-29.  So a time in 2015-03-31 would have correctly been in UTC+0100 instead of UTC+0000.

Comment: @LewBloch his date is in 2015, but still basically the same idea

Comment: @ajb Are saying that of all the random dates in the vast existence of time, I just happened to pick two which cross from UK Winter time to UK Summer time? I would never have checked that!

Comment: The probability is pretty good--why would this be a surprise?  All you have to do is pick one day of the year that's in Summer Time and one day of the year that isn't.  And since Summer Time takes up about half the year, the probability of crossing a time zone is somewhere around 50%.

Comment: As a computer programmer one must be aware that dates and times are one of the trickiest areas of software and think automatically to check such things.

Comment: It surprises me because I could have chosen any dates, like 2015-01-01 to 2015-01-02 :)

Comment: Side note: you should probably be moving away from Joda and toward `java.time`.

Comment: @ajb Interesting. I was told to use Jodatime!

Comment: Ah, right, 2015. I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The UK moves from Standard Time, `+00:00:00`, to Summer Time, `+01:00:00`, on March 26. No doubt you're running your program on a platform set to local UK time.

EDIT: In 2015 it was March 29.

Comment: Any way to make the DateTimes not add the extra hour?

Comment: @pookie Are you sure you want to?  Are you sure the database stores times in UTC, as opposed to London local time?  First make sure of that.

Comment: Yes, for the time being, I need to just to do result verifications. I'll come back to sorting the dates with timezones out at a later... date.

Comment: @pookie I'm not a Joda expert, but try `new DateTime(2015, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeZone.UTC);`.  I'm looking at http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html.  I don't know if this is the best way to do it.

Comment: The documentation explains how to set different time zones. Use UTC.